# unable to implement gRPC having issues with Protos\greet.proto: No such file or directory

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-6.0, visual-studio-2022, grpc-c#

I'm trying to use gRPC for one of the microservice using this [URL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/grpc/?view=aspnetcore-6.0) in ASP NET 6.0. I have also installed the required package "Grpc.AspNetCore" Version="2.48.0". But it still gives me compilation error about **'Protos\greet.proto: No such file or directory',  path\Could not make proto path relative 1
'**

[image][image][image]

I tried to make path relative but still no luck.

I'm running on visual studio 2022 and did make update to make sure that it is not because of update. I also tried creating another test project with gPRC project template and it worked but when i tried to add another service it gets failed again in test project too.

working with manual way for now.

Comment: The screenshot you posted shows that the `Protos` folder is missing. Changing the path won't fix anything. The source files simply aren't there. Did you delete the folder by mistake?

Comment: The page you link to is the overview that explains how each part and file works. The next page is [the tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/grpc/grpc-start?view=aspnetcore-6.0&tabs=visual-studio) that guides you step-by-step how and where to create the `.proto` files, how to compile them, how to run the project etc

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I haven't deleted the folder or anything it came as it is when i compiled the source code

Comment: The image you posted says otherwise. The `Protos` folder is clearly marked as missing.  `it came as it is when i compiled the source` but did you *create* that folder? Did you save the `proto` files in there? `.proto` files are source files, just like `.cs` files.

Comment: Have you tried following the [tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/grpc/grpc-start?view=aspnetcore-6.0&tabs=visual-studio) ?

Comment: It did worked when i created the folder and the file manually @PanagiotisKanavos